# JavaScript/jQuery: find arrangement with smallest difference in column size

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, math

I am trying to dynamically populate the contents of a page, based on JSON data. The JSON is an array of individual objects, each of which contains location data for various office locations.

So far I have been able to loop through all of the JSON, and create a list of unique state names (every state where an office exists), then use a constructor function to create a new State object that contains the name of the State, and an array of html objects for each office in that state (in alphabetical order). These state objects exist in a container array.

Here is an example of the container array and the constructed State objects:

```
var states = [State, State, State, State];

states[0].stateHTML => $('<li class="state">California</li>')
states[0].officeHTML => [Office, Office]
states[0].officeHTML[0] => $('<li class="office">' +
                             '<span>' + Some Office + '</span>' +
                             ...
                             '<span>' + Phone + '</span>' +
                             '</li>')
```

The problem I am stuck on is that this needs to be displayed in a 3 column layout, and I would like the columns to be roughly equal in size. Each column is a div, with a ul nested inside. I have tried taking the number of unique states, divided by three and then adding that many states to each column, but unfortunately the states do not contain equal quantities of offices, so this approach results in very uneven columns.

I was thinking that since I know the number of offices each state has, there has to be some way to calculate the assignments of each column such that the number of offices in each is closest to the total number of offices/3.

Example:

```
offices.length => 20
states.length => 6

states[0].offices.length => 7
states[1].offices.length => 2
states[2].offices.length => 1
states[3].offices.length => 4
states[4].offices.length => 5
states[5].offices.length => 1
```

So given 20 offices across 3 columns you would have about 6.66 offices/column. Just adding equal number of states to each column would be 2 states/column. But that would result in 9 offices in Column1, 5 in Column2, and 6 in Column3. However, given the total number of offices for each state the best way to display this would be:

```
Column1 => states[0] (7 offices)
Column2 => states[1,2,3] (7 offices)
Column3 => states[4,5] (6 offices)
```

P.S. I should mention if there is a way to do this using CSS (flex or something similar) I am open to that.  But I have been unsuccessful with this approach without hardcoding a max-height to the columns (which can't account for varying numbers of offices).

Edit: here is a codepen example of the rendered page http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JGYgEW

Comment: This is an optimization problem and you are trying to minimize the average height of the 3 columns content. And your constraints...can you repeat the same state at the top of the next column and continue? If so then it's pretty easy. If not, what nazi boss ... nevermind lol.

Comment: Maybe it'd be easier if you could extract the offices out into a single one-dimensional array, creating new objects that contain both the state information and the office information for each one. Then you just iterate through that list, apportioning out offices to each column.

Comment: @toddmo Unfortunately, the the ideal outcome would be to only have each state header once (I added a codepen example to the question). If it just isn't possible to do this without repeating the title, that could be a last resort.

Comment: Why don't you start assigning offices row-wise, with 3 columns each. Is it a restriction? That would always ensure minimum column height.

Comment: @BatScream Im not sure I understand that suggestion.  Going in a row would give equal column sizes, but (unless I'm mistaken) you wouldn't be able to group them vertically by state (as in the codepen example).

Comment: @Chad - you can group them. - you need to retrieve the *next* office item in the array - which belongs to the state *denoted* by the column.

Comment: @Pointy Wouldn't that result in repeating state headers?

Comment: I saw your code pen. Indeed you do need to use a new ES6 flex with wrapping from one column to the next (but only at state breaks), and a bottom margin "pushing" everything up as far as possible. That's the approach I'd try.

Comment: @Chad only if you didn't write code to avoid it. When your code moves from office to office, it can tell whether the state changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for fun, an approach without "cutting" states and keeping array order.
It populates columns using individual `states[n].offices.length` and an average base of slots aviliable for each column. Hope it helps!
http://jsfiddle.net/ch1qui/y1yva4w8/2/

Comment: Thanks! That's almost perfect, but I'm having an issue with my actual data.  It is moving onto #col[3], and I'm not sure how to fix that.  Here are the actual numbers:
`officesLen = 19
statesLen = 12
states = [];

states[0] = 1
states[1] = 3
states[2] = 4
states[3] = 2
states[4] = 1
states[5] = 1
states[6] = 1
states[7] = 1
states[8] = 1
states[9] = 1
states[10] = 2
states[11] = 1`

Comment: The problem is that the code wont cut any state offices, and the third state wont fit in the first column (leaving a total of 8 offices). To make a more even distribution you should allow a state to continue parsing offices in the next column: http://jsfiddle.net/ch1qui/y1yva4w8/4/

Comment: Thanks so much!  Not quite what I was hoping for, but I think its the best I can do without resorting to statistical math (standard deviation... I think) that I have long since forgotten.